# How I do evaluate a function handle in other function handle?(matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, function, ode

```
function [v] = f_dora(f,x0,y0,n)

p_y=@(f,x,y) (f(x,y+0.0001) - f(x,y-0.0001))/(2*0.0001);
p_x=@(f,x,y) (f(x+0.0001,y) - f(x-0.0001,y))/(2*0.0001);



for i=1:n   
    g=@(x,y) f(x,y)*p_y(f,x,y) + p_x(f,x,y)
    f=@(x,y) g(x,y)
end
v=f(x0,y0);
end
```

This function has a input f, like (f=@((x,y) y -x^2 +1), and want to has as output  $f^n(x,y)$ (the nth derivative of f, where y depends of x)

The steps that I follow to solve this problem are:

First, I define the function p_y and p_x that is the partial derivate aproximation of f.

And, I define the function g, which is the  (p_x + p_y*f(x,y))(this is the form of the derivate f)

Finally, I want to evaluate n times the function g_k in the same function, something like this:

```
g_1=@(x,y) f(x,y)*p_y(f,x,y) + p_x(f,x,y);    
g_2=@(x,y) g_1(x,y)*p_y(g_1,x,y) + p_x(g_1,x,y); 
.
.
.
g_n=@(x,y) g_(n-1)(x,y)*p_y(g_(n-1),x,y) + p_x(g_(n-1),x,y); 
g_n(x,y)
```

or

[Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fowp8.png)

But, when I use the first code I have incorrect results for n>=3.

A example to try the code, is using f_dora(@((x,y) y -x^2 +1,0,0.5,n), and for n=1, the result that would be correct is 1.5. For n=2,the result that would be correct is -0.5, for n=3. the result that would be correct is -0.5....

Someone could help me by seeing what the errors are in my code?, or does anyone know any better way to calculate partial derivatives without using the symbolic?

Comment: You should note that if you change the definition of a variable used in a previously defined anonymous function, the anonymous function is not updated to reflect this change. Check, `a=2; t = @(x) x^a; t(2)` returns 4. If you then redefine `a=3` `t(2)` is still 4 rather than 8.

Comment: It has a good point, but notice that g is updated for each iteration, that is,  `a=2; t=@(x) x^a` ; t(2), returns 4 , `a=4; t=@(x) x^a;` returns 8 @user12339314